# SQL Server insert Top nchar +1 that could start by 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to develop an insert query on sql server which inserts a nchar value from another nchar value, but I have to increment it by 1. I have to preserve the left 0 (not always be a 0). How can I make the conversion? This is my code:

```
DECLARE @CIG int;
SET @CIG = (SELECT MAX([VALUE1]) FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]) +1;
```

For example If I have:

```
0761600002511
```

the result will be:

```
0761600002512
```

if I have:

```
1761600002511
```

the result will be:

```
1761600002512
```

I have tried with something like this: (with the same conversion error and with the same problem with the possible starting 0)

```
SET @CIG =
    CAST
    (
        (CAST 
        (
            (
                SELECT MAX([VALUE1])FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE]
            )
         as int)+1)
    as nchar(100))
```

Thanks

Comment: VALUE1 is NCHAR data type ?? and what is length of it

Comment: Create an `identity` column using a `bigint`.  Don't try to do this with `max()` when the database has built-in functionality exactly for this purpose.

Comment: yes it is, I tried to pass it to int to add 1, but it doesn't apear to work and it still losing the 0

Comment: Don't do it. use identity as Gordon wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming That you have set NCHAR(10) length for your column, to preserve zero if there

```
DECLARE @tmp NCHAR(100) ='0761600002511';
SELECT LEFT(@tmp ,3)+CAST((CAST(RIGHT(@tmp ,97)AS INT)+1) AS NCHAR(10))
```

Comment: Thanks, That seems very interesting, but I have an error of 'overflowed an int column' (I have this in spanish so this is an translation of the error) I have nchar(100) (yes it is ridiculous, but is not my db) so I change your 10 for 100, but I don't know really what is the '3' value for (I tried with '13' too, but same error).

Answer (score 0):

You should Convert/cast first and then take max. Try this.

```
DECLARE @CIG int;
SELECT @CIG = MAX(CONVERT(INT, [VALUE1]) + 1 FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE];
```

Comment: Thanks, but whith this sintax I have an error on 'FROM' and still having the '0' problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use below udfLeftSQLPadding function.
First of all, calculate the integer value.
Then by using udfLeftSQLPadding [SQL pad leading zeros function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx), you can add zeros to the beginning of the number if necessary.

```
DECLARE @CIG bigint = 761600002511
set @CIG = @CIG + 1
select dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding( cast(@CIG as varchar(13)),13,'0')
```

I assumed that you require 13 character long string at the end, so I used 13 twice above. Once in CAST() function and once for the udfLeftSQLPadding function

I hope it helps,